# Is it possible to autowire dependencies that are created outside of an ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jax-rs

I've got an application which uses JAXRS to map Restlet resources using annotations. However, the only entry point I have is essentially defining a list of resource classes in the application configuration. These classes are instantiated by Restlet or JAXRS, so I have no way to put them in my `ApplicationContext`. Is there a way to have Spring scan the classpath and autowire new instances as necessary? I've already tried using something like below:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't really work. Is there a way to do what I'm talking about here?

Comment: what do you have in your classpath?

Comment: After I answered your question I started to question myself did I read your's correctly :P Just to clarify, are you trying to inject stuff into classes instantiated by Restlet or trying to inject those classes into classes in your ApplicationContext?

Comment: I'm trying to autowire dependencies _into_ classes created outside of my control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AspectJ to dependency inject your beans that are created out of your control, or if you create objects using new. You can read more on Springs documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj

Essentially what you will do is add @Configurable annotation to the class that you want to be target of injection. You also have to enable it in Spring by having  in your Spring xml. Lastly you have to decide between compile time weaving or runtime weaving. Again you can get help from spring documentation.

Loadtime weaving: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

If you use maven you can check this Stackoverflow question for setting up compile time AspectJ: [Why doesn't AspectJ compile-time weaving of Spring's @Configurable work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901632/why-doesnt-aspectj-compile-time-weaving-of-springs-configurable-work)

Answer (score 4):

`ApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(object)` will inject all dependencies into the object.