# How to configure Spring to use aspectj for Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, maven, proxy, aspectj

According this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429757/2674303
To use `@Transactional` when I execute local method I did following steps:

added to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

replace in context

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

with

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>
```

after it I saw

> Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

additionally added:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

But when make `mvn clean install` I see(problem occures when tests try to execute. In my test I up appliction context):

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    ....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)

    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)

    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1590)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 54 more
```

### update

entire `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.terminal</groupId>
    <artifactId>terminal-company</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>terminal-company</name>


    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
        <jetty.version>9.2.5.v20141112</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.182</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Integration-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- other -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.56.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>terminal-company</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/basic.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/braces.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml</ruleset>
                        <!--<ruleset>rulesets/java/codesize.xml</ruleset>-->
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/imports.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/empty.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/jsp/basic.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>ruleset-naming.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**\/*.jsp</include>
                        <include>**\/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeFromFailureFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/exclude-pmd.properties
                            </excludeFromFailureFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>terminal-company</warName>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>8081</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.1.15.v20140411</version>
                                    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/marc_db</url>
                    <user>marc</user>
                    <password>marc</password>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repo</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <name>JBoss Repo</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>glassfish-repository</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
            <snapshots>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

### update 2:

If skip test phase while building application - **build success** and then run `mvn clean install jetty:run` I see following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: protected abstract void org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$pointcut$$transactionalMethodExecution$e12(java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: protected abstract void org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$pointcut$$transactionalMethodExecution$e12(java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:166)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    ... 76 more
13.11.2015 04:57:35 ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect': Post-processing failed of bean type [class org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: protected abstract void org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$pointcut$$transactionalMethodExecution$e12(java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: protected abstract void org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$pointcut$$transactionalMethodExecution$e12(java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:91) 
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)   
    ... 76 more
```

### update 3

Also I tried to add

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving= EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class Configiuration {
```

I see same result

### update 4:

class which uses Transactional annotation:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.refreshStopJobs();
    }
    ...
}
```

### Solution

Actually [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920671/2674303) wa helpful for me

Comment: @duffymo: Spring's Transaction support via AspectJ is build in.

Comment: @duffymo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo

Comment: Unless they changed it, Spring 1.0 didn't have AspectJ, but it did have transactions.  Used vanilla Spring aspects.

Comment: Could you post your entire POM?

Comment: @Tunaki topic updated

Comment: @gstackoverflow You say in your post that the error occus when running `mvn clean install`. Is that true or is it when the application is deployed?

Comment: @Tunaki is it true because It  breaks on test phase. if skip this phase and run mvn clean install jetty:run  I see a bit another error. Please let me a minute ti update topic

Comment: @Tunaki topic updated

Comment: You use bom spring and  direct dependency   <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> ?, can you doing mvn dependency:tree

Comment: @http://textuploader.com/56jzp I cannot paste result in my topic because topic size is limited. You can see result here: http://textuploader.com/56jzp

Comment: Can you post the class where you are using the @Transactional annotation?

Comment: @LucasP topicc updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically to make AspectJ Load Time Weaving to work you need at first think of environment your app is going to work. As the name says the "load time" means that your classes are going to be changed by classloader. So from your question I understand that you need yours LTW in two environment. First is the "Test" environment that is command line and second is the Servlet Container (Jetty/Tomcat).

So lets start from the Test Environment: Your tests are failing because classloader has no chance to edit/instrument/weave you classes, Spring can't help you as it isn't yet running and you have chosen Load Time over Run Time Weaving. So we need somehow tell the default classloader that we are going to hack to classes. This is documented at [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) To do so we need to add `-javaagent` which in our case instead of instrumenting/profiling runtime will just change the classes at load time. To achieve this just tell maven to add 2 `javaaganets` : the `aspectj-weaver-x.jar` and special `spring-instrument-x.jar`, so just in your maven `plugins` section add.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/4.2.2.RELEASE/spring-instrument-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.7/aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar
            </argLine>
            <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Just remember to add `spring-instrument-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar` as dependency at least in `provided` scope to be sure that it is in the repo ;)
After adding this configuration settings you tests execution will work fine. Just try:

`mvn clean package`

Next lets start with the second environment the Servlet Container.
If you are running Tomcat then you are happy, as you can overrride default classloader by the one which is shipped with spring by adding following `META-INF/context.xml` to your project.

```
<Context path="/myWebApp" docBase="/my/webApp/location">
    <Loader
    loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environment-tomcat). For Jetty you should manually edit the run script and add two `-javaagent`s as we have done for maven test environment.

Comment: I use jetty. Why does it so hard?

Comment: It is not that hard, but Spring guys do not support Jettys clasloader, so you need just edit the run script and add the java agents to the Jetty start-up script ...

Comment: Ok. I am trying to run with tomcat from local idea- Error:ajc: invalid source option, source is either '1.3' or '1.4': 8

Comment: Bro, I have never used Idea, so for proof of concept just run Tomcat in standalone mode. So create the .war file. Put it int the webapps and start the Tomcat using startup.sh script.

Comment: Ok, it getting more and more interesting ;) just to help you with your case, create  sinple projet based on the one which you are developing, push it to github and share the link, I'll create a PR for you with working stuf ,)

Comment: on tomcat I see. Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread. aspectj should fix this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95113/discussion-between-babl-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: for those having "Error:ajc: invalid source option, source is either" check the version of the ajc compiler that you are using. You can run into this problem using aspectjtools-1.6.1.jar as ajc and  target byte code version of 1.8

Answer (score 0):

In the XML config you used

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

however with the default mode autodect load time weaving will only be done if you have a META-INF/aop.xml file. Since you don't seem to have one you should change it to

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>
```

or add an META-INF/aop.xml.
I see you did do that in the Java config, but it seems you the bulk of your config in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to refer this useful link:

Spring 2.0 AOP - Spring 2.0 introduces a simpler and more powerful way of writing custom aspects using either a schema-based approach or the **@AspectJ** annotation style. Both of these styles offer fully typed advice and use of the AspectJ pointcut language, while still using Spring AOP for weaving.

The Spring 2.0 schema- and @AspectJ-based AOP support is discussed in this chapter. Spring 2.0 AOP remains fully backwards compatible with Spring 1.2 AOP, and the lower-level AOP support offered by the Spring 1.2 APIs is discussed in the following chapter.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html